# HTTP headers in response data from Express server in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, safari

My angular app is making a call to my API from a ui-router resolve:

```
...
$stateProvider
    .state('gallery',{
        abstract: true, 
        templateUrl: 'components/gallery/gallery.html'
    })
    .state('gallery.views', {
        url: "/{gallery:shades-of-gray|color}",
        views: {
            'left@gallery': {
                templateUrl: 'components/gallery/partials/gallery-slider.html',
                controller: 'SliderController'
            },
            'right@gallery': {
                templateUrl: 'components/gallery/partials/gallery-img.html',
                controller: 'GalleryImgController'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            apiFactory: 'apiFactory',
            drawings: function(apiFactory, $stateParams){
                var param = $stateParams.gallery === 'color' ? 'color' : 'bw';
                return apiFactory.getImageUrls(param);
            }
        }
    });
...
```

My ApiFactory simply makes an API call and resolves the promise:

```
apiFactory.getImageUrls = function(gallery){
    if (gallery === undefined)
        var gallery = 'all';

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: API_URL + '/drawings/' + gallery,
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.data.gallery;
    });
};
```

And my two controllers use the data injected by my resolve:

```
.controller('SliderController', function($scope, drawings){
    $scope.drawings = drawings;
    ...
}
controller('GalleryImgController', function($scope, drawings){
   $scope.currentDrawing = drawings[0];
   ...
}
```

In Safari, I wait **120 seconds** for the `$http` promise to resolve, at which point I see my response with proper status code, headers etc. However (unlike Firefox in Chrome), `response.data` is a string containing the HTTP headers:

[image]

I can't parse it reliably (because I'll have an `Authorization` header with some responses). What gives? Why is this a problem on Safari and what can I do about it?

If it helps, here is the Express code that responds to the request:

```
...
getDrawingSet(gallery, (err, drawings) => {
    if (err)
        return next(err);
    let ret = {};
    ret["gallery"] = drawings;
    res.status(httpStatus[200]).json(ret);
});
...
```

Where `drawings` is just an array of JSON objects. Thanks.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but in your apiFactory.getImageUrls method you can kill that success handler...the code: ".then(function(response){ return response.data.gallery; });" does nothing, just returns the response data to the $http closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The issue was on the server (obviously).

I simply changed the following line from:

```
res.sendStatus(200).json(ret);
```

to

```
res.status(200).json(ret);
```

Which can really be simplified to `res.json(ret)`.

From the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus) for `res.sendStatus()`:

*Set the response HTTP status code to `statusCode` and send its string representation as the response body.*

Contrast this with `res.status()`:

*Use this method to set the HTTP status for the response.*

I thought I was doing the latter with the former. However Firefox and Chrome allowed me to get away with this I'm not entirely sure, but I'm certainly happy that Safari brought this error to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

> In Safari, I wait **120 seconds** for the $http promise to resolve, at
>   which point I see my response with proper status code, headers etc.
>   However (unlike Firefox in Chrome), `response.data` is a string
>   containing the HTTP headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 OK unknown
```

-> This is not a valid [HTTP response header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).

> **6.1 Status-Line**
>
> The first line of a Response message is the Status-Line, consisting of
>   the protocol version followed by a numeric status code and its
>   associated textual phrase, with each element separated by SP
>   characters. No CR or LF is allowed except in the final CRLF sequence.
>
> ```
>    Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
> ```

Should be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Maybe Safari does not accept this as a header and pushes the header data towards the response? Or do you receive other headers before this?